# How to display a color alertbox

Tags: javascript, alert

How do I add color in a Alert box in JavaScript? The whole box must be colored and the text must be bold. I tried to add color to them using CSS property, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, alerts are separated from your content. They are new windows managed by the browser, and there is no way to style them.

You can create a fake one (example: a full size div that opens with Javascript) that contains HTML, you'll be able to style that one.